# How to wrap text in a TexView?

Tags: android, textview, word-wrap

Here is my layout:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="2" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgdesc" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_row="1"/>

</GridLayout>
```

And here is the result:

[image: result]

As you can see, a part of the text is out the screen and I don't really know how to fix it.

Comment: tried using `wrap_content` for tvDescription's width?

Comment: yes I did. Actually it was `wrap_content` at first, I tried `fill_parent` and forgot to change it when i copied my code.

Comment: I tried giving fixed width, it worked, but why gridlayout btw? If not for a particular reason, then this layout can be implemented using RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use LinearLayout for your design instead of GridLayout :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgdesc"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace below code with your current code, hope this work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="2" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_rowSpan="2"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" // this line change
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:ems="5"  //this line added
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:ems="5"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_row="1" />

</GridLayout>
```

**Note: there can be a many ways to do the same.**

Answer (score 0):

try below code, it will work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_rowSpan="2"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:contentDescription="test" />
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_row="1"/>
 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```